# Boolean union modifier doesn't look right

Tags: modifiers

I have a boolean modifier attached to the circle set to union with the curve object. I'm unsure why there is a strange line where the two shapes overlap even when the curve object is hidden from the viewport. I've recalculated the normals to face outwards on both meshes and I've checked if there are any overlapping faces and i'm pretty sure there aren't any.
Please help, thank you.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The boolean modifier has a strange behavior on overlapping faces.
If you set (in the boolean modifier panel) the threshold=0 it solves the problem on the top face but it remains on the bottom face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to fix:

- I set the Overlap Threshold of the boolean to 0.
- I moved the bottom face of the Curve.001 down by -0.0001 mm

[image]

Comment: thanks this looks great. It also works when a solidify modifier is applied to the curve with thickness set to around 0.0001.